# Ruby on Rails で before_actionの中に定義した変数をアクションの中でも使いたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

before_actionの中で値を設定した変数をアクションの中でも使う方法ってありますか？

たとえば、before_actionにhogeを指定した状態でhugaを呼び出した時、

```
before_action :hoge

def hoge
    val = "abc"
end

def huga
    puts val
end
```

> abc

となるのを期待しているのですが、そもそも出来るんでしょうか？

クラス変数を使うのが素直？

Comment: 回答をみたあとあーーーって思ったんですが、私が「クラス変数」と言っていたのは「インスタンス変数」の事でした。C++とRubyがごっちゃになって２つの変数の違いを曖昧にしていました。一度インスタンス変数で実験してみたら上手く行かなかったので、なんじゃこりゃと思って質問させて頂きました。これについてはもう一回トライしてみます。ただ、今回の質問の意図としては、インスタンス変数を使うのがエレガントでは無いと思ったからです。メソッドの呼び出しを抜けても値が保存され続けるから、他のメソッドでその変数を参照した時に事故るかもしれない、という安全性を考えてのことです。ですので、before_actionが「メソッドからbefore_actionで定義されたメソッドを呼び出す」というものであるんだとしたら、before_actionで値を返すとか、そんな方法があるのかなと思った次第です。回答していただいた方ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

できません。インスタンス変数を使うのが最も簡単です。

```
before_action :hoge

def hoge
    @val = "abc"
end

def huga
    puts @val
end
```

処理した内容をメモ化しておいてメソッド名でアクセスする方法もあります。

```
before_action :hoge

def hoge
    @val ||= "abc"
end

def huga
    puts hoge
end
```

before_actionで一度hogeはよばれていますが`"abc"`は一度しか生成されません。

Comment: ピッタシの回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

before_actionはRailsのActionController::Baseクラスに含まれるメソッドに
すぎません。

「できません」では言葉足らずかと思います、ローカル変数は名前のとおり、
メソッド間で共有できません、インスタンス変数は同ーインスタンスの
メソッド間で共有できます。(蛇足で言わずもがなですが、クラス変数は
名前のとおり、  同一クラス間で共有できます。)

同一インスタンス内で共有したいのなら、インスタンス変数を使うことになります。
同一インスタンス内で共有する目的でクラス変数を用いるべきではありません。

Rails云々の前にRubyのクラスまわりの基礎を見なおして理解することを
オススメします。

Comment: > 同一インスタンス内で共有する目的でクラス変数を用いるべきではありません。
そこが引っかかってたんです。そんな方法でしか実現できないのかなと。

> インスタンス変数は同ーインスタンスのメソッド間で共有できます。
私はこれを勉強しなければならないのですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

先のお二方のご回答で十二分かと思いますが、姑事ながら一点だけ

値のキャッシングや`before_action`のためのメソッドはよほどの事が無い限り`private`にし`Controller`内（もしくはそのサブクラス）専用である事を示しておくと良いかもです.

（`before_action` と値のキャッシングを兼ねるのは別途議論が必要ですが）

```
before_action :hoge

def huga
  val = hoge
end

private
  def hoge
    @val ||= "abc"
  end
```

もうご存知で、質問or回答を簡潔にするための省略でしたら失礼しました.